# Redpark Serial Cable not receiving data

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, serial-port, mfi

I have a C2-DB9 serial cable from Redpark for use with an iOS application that seems to be not working as required. I have a device that connects to the RSC cable and also to a PC via USB for power only.

I have utilised the Redpark SDK provided with the hardware and implemented the delegate methods accordingly:

```
- (void) cableConnected:(NSString *)protocol;

- (void) cableDisconnected;

- (void) portStatusChanged;

- (void) readBytesAvailable:(UInt32)length;
```

Now, all of the methods apart from readBytesAvailable behave according to specification. However, I have not received any communication back via this delegated method.

To check that the device is not faulty, I have installed some generic USB to Serial drivers and used ZTerm to confirm its operation - this gives me the returned data immediately.

I know I must be missing something but I am at a loss as to what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you setting baud rate and opening connection via RscMgr's *setBaud* and *open* methods on

- (void) cableConnected:(NSString *)protocol;

Comment: I am indeed. I am now in fact receiving the data but I am having trouble reading from the UInt8 buffer.

Comment: `cableConnected:(NSString *)protocol` doesn't seem to be called for me when I plug the cable in. What should I do...?

Comment: I'm in the same situation as you, my readBytesAvailable is never called. What did you do ?